# Intuition behind Jensen Shannon divergence between deep features of two images?

Tags: deep-learning, probability, distribution, features

Jensen Shanon divergence is mainly used to determine the divergence between two probability distributions. Can it be used to calculate the difference between the deep feature vectors of two images?

I have used the image deep feature vectors directly as a probability distribution to check the similarity between two images and the results are good.

Next, I also normalized the feature vectors by dividing them by the sum of the vector, to convert them to some form of probability distribution. The results were the same as earlier.

But I am unable to get the intuition behind the "good" performance. Can JSD be used as a comparison metric of deep features?